# Insert into MYSQL table last submission date for a review

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table called 'ratings' which contains an index which is a unique ascending number, ProductId which is a product code, rate1 to rate5 are the number of times each product has recieved a 1 or 5 star rating by a customer aveRate is the average rating for each product and lastSubDate should be the timestamp of when the last review for each product was submitted but it's currently empty.

```
id  ProductId   rate1   rate2   rate3   rate4   rate5   aveRate     lastSubDate


18  9996637     0   0   0   0   1   5   0000-00-00 00:00:00
26  9996628     1   0   0   0   0   1   0000-00-00 00:00:00
34  9996618     0   0   0   1   0   4   0000-00-00 00:00:00
36  9996614     5   0   0   0   0   1   0000-00-00 00:00:00
48  9996592     5   0   1   0   3   3   0000-00-00 00:00:00
66  9996566     0   0   0   1   3   5   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

In another table I have called 'last_rate_date' I have ProductId and the date the product was last rated under lastSubDate. In this table the Product Id's can appear several times as per the example as each row represents a time a review was submitted by a customer.

```
ProductId   lastSubDate
9996665     2009-05-22 19:45:05
9996665     2009-08-06 11:30:07
9996665     2010-11-10 08:30:17
9996665     2011-06-10 09:15:47
9996665     2011-06-12 05:15:39
```

My questions is how can I modify the first table 'ratings' using SQL to insert the last time a product was reviewed under the 'lastSubDate' using the second table 'last_rate_date' to lookup the productId and the date bearing in mind each ProductId may appear mutiple times in this seconds table with differen't dates.

This needs to be one as a one off table modification to the first table. Adter this is done I will amend the script which adds data to ratings table to always add a timestamp in the future when it's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most recent dates for each "ProductId" using the query below:

```
Select ProductId, MAX(lastSubDate)
From last_rate_date
Group By ProductId
```

This will produce each ProductId that appears in the second table, along with the latest date (using the MAX function). The Group By clause is needed to define what the aggregation is run against.

To further solve your problem, you can insert this Select statement into an Update statement like so:

```
UPDATE ratings a
INNER JOIN (
    Select ProductId, MAX(lastSubDate) as finalLastSubDate
    From last_rate_date
    Group By ProductId ) b
ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId
SET a.lastSubDate = b.finalLastSubDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the timestamp with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default
or you can add the date on the insert.

```
$date = date ("m-Y-d, H: i: s")
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood my question or perhaps I need to clarify. I have all the data I need in the second MySQL table and I need to modify the first using data from the second as a one off table modification. I will ofcourse then amend the script which maintains the table to always insert the timestamp from now on for any future records added.